# Prove the theorem of equivalence class

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be equivalence relation on $A$, and let $A_x$ be equivalence of $R$ which contain $x$,
$$A_x=\{a\in A\mid (a,x)\in R\}.$$
Prove if $y\in A_x$ then $A_x=A_y$.

> This is my effort:
>
> Given $y\in A_x$ so $y\in A$ such that $(y,x)\in R$. Because of $R$ is
> equivalence relation,  $$(x,y)\in R.$$ We have $x\in A$ such that
> $(x,y)\in R$. So, $x\in A_y$.

I'm confused and I can't prove this theorem. How we can get $A_x=A_y$?

Comment: How to prove equality of two sets? What is the recipe? Well, you need to prove that A_x is contained in A_z and vice versa. What is the recipe to prove containment? You need to take an arbitrary element z from A_x and prove that z belongs also to A_y.  Try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to prove that $A_y \subseteq A_x$ and $A_x \subseteq A_y$.

- $A_y \subseteq A_x$:
  Let $z \in A_y$. Then $z \sim y$. Since $y \sim x$, we get $z \sim x$ by transitivity. Thus, $z \in A_x$.
- $A_x \subseteq A_y$:
  Let $z \in A_x$. Then $z \sim x$. Since $y \sim x$, we get $x \sim y$ by symmetry and so $z \sim y$ by transitivity. Thus, $z \in A_y$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:

Use symmetry to prove that, if $y\in A_x$, then $x\in A_y$.

Use transitivity  to prove that $A_y\subseteq A_x$.

Answer (score 1):

If $y \in A_x$, then to show $A_x = A_y$ try showing that $A_x \subseteq A_y$ and $A_y \subseteq A_x$.

For the first inclusion, if $a \in A_x$, then $(a,x) \in R$. But since $y \in A_x$, $(y,x) \in R$. Transitivity means $(a,y) \in R$ so $a \in A_y$.

I'll leave the other inclusion for you to try.